# Multithreading in Grails - Passing domain objects into each thread causes some fields to randomly be null

Tags: java, multithreading, grails, groovy, threadpool

I am trying to speed up a process in a Grails application by introducing parallel programming. This particular process requires sifting through thousands of documents, gathering the necessary data from them and exporting it to an excel file.

After many hours of trying to track down why this process was going so slowly, I've determined that the process has to do a lot of work gathering specific parts of data from each domain object. (Example: The domain object has lists of data inside it, and this process takes each index in these lists and appends it to a string with commas to make a nice looking, sorted list in a cell of the excel sheet. There are more examples but those shouldn't be important.)

So anything that wasn't a simple data access (document.id, document.name, etc...) was causing this process to take a long time.

My idea was to use threads for each document to asynchronously acquire all this data, when each thread finished gathering the data, it can come back to the main thread and be placed into the excel sheet, now all with simple data access, because the thread already gathered all the data.

This seems to be working, however I have a bug with the domain objects and the threads. Each thread is passed in its corresponding document domain object, but for whatever reason, the document domain objects will randomly have parts of its data changed to null.

For example: Before the document is passed into the thread, one part of the domain object will have a list that looks like this: [US, England, Wales], randomly at any point, the list will look like this in the thread: [US, null, Wales]. And this happens for any random part of the domain object, at any random time.

Generating the threads:

```
def docThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
def docThreadsResults = new Future<Map>[filteredDocs.size()]
filteredDocs.each {
    def final document = it
    def future = docThreadPool.submit(new DocumentExportCallable(document))
    docThreadsResults[docCount] = future
    docCount++
}
```

Getting the data back from the threads:

```
filteredDocs.each {
        def data = docThreadsResults[count].get()

        build excel spreadsheet...
}
```

DocumentExportCallable class:

```
class DocumentExportCallable implements Callable {
    def final document

    DocumentExportCallable(document) {
        this.document = document
    }

    Map call() {
            def data = [:]

            code to get all the data...

            return data
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As seen below, it would be useful if I could show you the domain object. However I am not able to do this. BUT, the fact that you guys asked me about the domain object had me thinking that it just might be where the problem lies. Turns out, every part of the domain object that randomly messes up in the threads is a variable in the domain object inside "mapping" which uses SQL joins to get the data for those variables. I've just been made aware of lazy vs eager fetching in Grails. I'm wondering if this might be where the problem lies...by default it is set to lazy fetching so this constant access to the db by each thread might be where things are going wrong. I believe finding a way to change this to eager fetching might solve the problem.

Comment: Where's the domain object in the question?

Comment: Would seeing the guts of the domain object help with figuring out the issue? I'm a little reluctant to post that as I am not sure if I am allowed to.

Comment: Are you using the map constructor to create your domain objects? I had issues such as yours creating lots of domain objects rapidly when switching from grails 2 to 3, resorted to setting fields individually eventually e.g. domain.field1 = field1value

Comment: @MikeW I'm not creating any of the domain objects, the objects are coming from a SQL lookup and stored in that filteredDocs variable above. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: either way the most important bit that tim has point out isn't there to fully understand the model. Try wrapping a witNewTransaction try adding some sleepers in your threaded executors - try most importantly enabling sql logging to figure out what happened when it got a null. it could be a case of a good old hammering and I give up boss that you are not aware of

Comment: @vahid Thank you for the reply!! I am currently in the process of trying out some new ideas based on what you've said. Check the edit above, it might ring a bell for you that I am not aware of.

Comment: You seen https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/async.html ?

Comment: @tim_yates I have seen that, I wasn't sure if it was worth learning more about as it seemed I could get this done with the Executors package. Changing the domain object to eager fetching got rid of the weird null errors I was getting in the post above, but now I need to figure out how to make it eager ONLY for this query, not the whole domain object across the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer to why these null values were appearing randomly. Everything seems to be working now and my implementation is now performing much faster than the previous implementation!

Turns out I was unaware that Grails domain objects with 1-m relationships make separate sql calls when you access these fields even after you get the object itself. This must have caused these threads to be making un-thread-safe sql calls which created these random null values. Setting these 1-m properties in this specific case to be eagerly fetched fixed the issue.

For anyone reading later on, you'll want to read up on lazy vs eager fetching to get a better understanding.

As for the code:

These are the 1-m variables that were the issue in my domain object:

```
static hasMany = [propertyOne : OtherDomainObject, propertyTwo : OtherDomainObject, propertyThree : OtherDomainObject]
```

I added a flag to my database call which would enable this code for this specific case, as I didn't want these properties to always be eagerly fetched throughout the app:

```
if (isEager) {
    fetchMode 'propertyOne', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'propertyTwo', FetchMode.JOIN
    fetchMode 'propertyThree', FetchMode.JOIN
    setResultTransformer Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
}
```

My apologies, but at the moment I do not remember why I had to put the "setResultTransformer" in the code above, but without it there were issues. Maybe someone later on can explain this, otherwise I'm sure a google search will explain.

Comment: When you eagerly fetch a one-to-many association, hibernate will do a DB join, which causing multiple result rows to be returned for the same base record. Hibernate will return an object for each row in the SQL result set, so you will get duplicates. DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY eliminates the duplicates. Aside: I've found in the past that this transformer is not performant for large result sets. In these cases, it's better to use batch size settings on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your grails domain objects were detaching from the hibernate session thus hitting LazyInitiationException when your thread attempted to load lazy properties.

It's good that switching to eager fetching worked for you but it may not be an option for everyone. What you could have also done is used grails async task framework instead as it has built in session handling. See https://async.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html

However, even with grails async task passing an object between threads seems to detach it as the new thread will have a newly bound session. The solutions that I have found where to either `.attach()` or `.merge()` on the new thread to bind it with the session on the calling thread.

I believe the optimal solution would be to have hibernate load the object on the new thread, meaning in your code snippet you would pass a document id and `Document.get(id)` on your session supported thread.